# MVC4 Render Html.Partial based on the screen resolution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a View and I want to render a specific partial depends on the size of the window.

The View looks:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "search", FormMethod.Get))
 {
         @Html.Partial("_Search")  

         <div class="searchmob" style="display: none;">
                 <h1>mobile</h1>
                 @Html.Partial("_SearchComponentMobile")  
         </div>
 }
```

by default the div searchmob is invisible and when making the screen smaller the div appears (it works)

The problem both of the partials contain textbox @Html.TextBox with the same name so when submitting from   _SearchComponentMobile it sends the _Search's textbox value.

Is it possible to render specific partial when required.

I used in one of my views the below code but in the above saturation it is related to a css, was hoping something similar can be accomplished:

```
@{
   var act = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().ToUpper();
}

@if (@act == "INDEX")
{
        //render a partial view otherwise it doesn't 
}
```

I am using bootstrap maybe this can also help me?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `DisplayModeProviders` built into MVC?
Essentially the view engine will look for 'overrides' of your views if the request is coming from a mobile platform.

So your main view would look like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "search", FormMethod.Get))
{
     @Html.Partial("_Search")  
}
```

Then rename your `_SearchComponentMobile.cshtml` to `_Search.mobile.cshtml` and let MVC take care of the rest (note you'll need to move you `<div class="searchmob">` into the partial if it has styling associated with it)

More info here if you need it:

- http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features
- http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingASwitchableDesktopAndMobileSiteWithASPNETMVC4AndJQueryMobile.aspx

---

**EDIT**

Otherwise repeat the form inside the mobile layout....

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "search", FormMethod.Get))
{
     @Html.Partial("_Search")  
}

<div class="searchmob" style="display: none;">
    <h1>mobile</h1>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "search", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        @Html.Partial("_SearchComponentMobile")  
    }
</div>
```

Comment: the problem with this, if the user makes the screen smaller on the desktop, I need to render the correct partial and with DisplayModeProviders it only works if mobile device is used.

Comment: @Ron if you're after a completely responsive layout on desktop too, then your solution will most likely be CSS driven. You'll need to analyse the differences within the markup and CSS between the desktop and mobile search layouts. Based on what you've shown us, the markup should be similar (both search boxes render in the same region), so work out what the differences are in the CSS and work out a style for both layouts, rather than just hiding/showing the box.